# Deleting values in array (MongoDB and mongoose)

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection. In this collection I have only one document like this:

```
_id:
emails: []
```

I would like to delete the values in emails array.

My code under /models/askForReferral.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const WaitingForReferral = mongoose.model('WaitingForReferral', new mongoose.Schema({

    emails: []

}));

exports.WaitingForReferral = WaitingForReferral;
```

My code under /routes/referralEmail.js:

```
const { WaitingForReferral } = require('../models/askForReferral');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    WaitingForReferral.update(
        { },
        { $unset: { emails: "" } }
     )

});
```

When I run my code, it runs without error, but emails array is not emptied.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$set` operator with blank array `[]` and also mongoose query returns promise you need to use `await` to execute it

```
await WaitingForReferral.update(
  { },
  { $set: { emails: [] } }
)
```